# Convert from string to tuple with "\" in python

Tags: python, command-line, tuples

I transport data from command line to python. And I want to convert from string (command line) to tuple (python). But I have problem with \ charactor.

In command line, I using:

```
C:\>python music.py -a variable="?=="
```

In python:

```
#convert variable to array 
variable_array = variable.split("==")
#convert to tuple
variable_tuple = tuple(variable_array)
```

I get variable_tuple = ("?","")

The result what I need is variable_tuple = ("\?","")

When using

```
C:\>python music.py -a variable="\?=="
```

The result is variable_tuple = ("\\?","")

How can I transport data from command line to get tuple ("\?","") in python? I need backslash for "?"

Comment: Try `print '\\?'` in a prompt; it is *already* giving you what you want, but since a python literal uses `\` as an escape character it is escaping the escape character to make it a valid string literal.

Comment: If input is "\\?", we will get ("\\\\?")

Comment: There's no problem here: `assert variable_tuple == (r"\?", "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'\\?'` is a string with one backslash character and a question mark. 
Using `list` is a convenient trick for spliting a string into characters. For example:

```
In [34]: list('\\?')
Out[34]: ['\\', '?']
```

shows `'\\?'` is composed of 2 characters, not 3. And if you print it:

```
In [35]: print('\\')
\
```

you see it prints as just one backslash character. The double backslash, `'\\'`, is an [escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-escapeseq).

---

Note also that when you print a tuple, you get the [repr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/190597) of its contents:

```
In [36]: print(tuple('\\?'))
('\\', '?')
```

---

`'\?'` is the exact same string as `'\\?'` in Python. They are simply different ways of representing the same string:

```
In [38]: list('\?')
Out[38]: ['\\', '?']

In [39]: list('\\?')
Out[39]: ['\\', '?']    

In [42]: '\?' is '\\?'
Out[44]: True
```

Comment: If input is "\\?", we will get ("\\\\?")

Comment: @hoangvu68: I don't have Windows to check, but yes, I believe so.

Comment: @unutbu: I need backslash for "?" ("\?"). I don't want to add backslash before "\".

Comment: You need to make a clear distinction between the way strings are represented, eg `'\\?'`, and the way they are printed, e.g. `\?`. If you want a **single** backslash followed by a question mark, then the way that string is **represented** in Python is `'\\?'`.

Comment: Python chooses to represent this string as `'\\?'` even though `'\?'` represents the same string. You won't be able to change the way Python behaves in this respect without hacking the source code and recompiling Python.

Comment: @unutbu: Thank you. I resloved it :)

Answer (score 0):

You get exactly what you want. What you see is just the string represenation for '\' with the first '\' as escape character.

Comment: No, I want to get ("\?"), not ("\\?").

Answer (score 0):

`("\\?","")` means that the '\' is escaped, otherwise '\?' would be interpreted as escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

？need not to be backslashed. So what you get is right and enough.